# Architecture for a remote database for a mobile application

Tags: java, database, oracle, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a mobile app which needs a secondary persistent store.
Locally, it is using both a SQLite3 database and the filesystem. The repository pattern is used to facilitate access to the data stores, thus the app does not know whether data comes from the filesystem or SQLite3.

I need to expand the app; so it can use a remote datastore.

The app stores both raw data, and short strings. Each 'item' is between 5 and 100 KiB. The total size of the data store is typically less than 200 MiB, but could grow up to 3 GiB in an extreme (rare) case.

My current idea is a RESTful webservice. ("Nothing is more dangerous than an idea if it's the only one you have." - Emil-Auguste Chartier.)

I am looking for a known architecture and design patterns to guide me.
I am unfamiliar with webservices in general, I need documented patterns to guide the design. Ideas?